# FTP CLient Stack

Tags: c

How to develop a FTP client stack? Can some one provide me with some link where I can find a tutorial about it please..

Comment: Developing an FTP-client is not that hard, but what is an **FTP client stack**?

Comment: @Konerak presumably the OP means API?

Answer (score 0):

Start at the first FTP RFC and work your way through the addendums:

- http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc959.html
- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3659
- http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2577.txt
- http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1579.html
- http://www.rfc-archive.org/getrfc.php?rfc=4217

etc, ...